# Prove that the limit of $\sqrt{x} e^{\sin(\pi/x)}$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't know what a correct answer is.  Graphing the function with a computer doesn't make it too clear, but it seems to say that it approaches zero from the right.  There's a good chance this problem might be expecting me to use the Squeeze Theorem, but perhaps it might be the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.  I'm not sure.

**An attempt**. I first look at what happens to $\pi/x$ as $x$ approaches 0 from the right.  I conclude it goes to infinity.  Then I consider what happens to $\sin(\pi/x)$ and I conclude it oscillates around $-1$ and $1$, that is, $$-1 \leq \sin(\pi/x) \leq 1.$$  Then I raise $e$ to both inequalities and I get $$e^{-1} \leq \sin(\pi/x) \leq e.$$  Now I multiply both inequalities by $\sqrt{x}$, getting $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{e} \leq \sqrt{x} e^{\sin(\pi/x)} \leq e \sqrt{x}$$ and by the Squeeze Theorem I would be able to say that it goes to zero.

**Related question**.  What happens if we let $x$ approach $0$ from the left?  [It seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637280) that the function would also approach zero, but perhaps my book is avoiding the question of what happens when we consider values of the function outside of the domain --- by only asking what happens when the function is not undefined.

**Another possible solution**. I [believe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855217) the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality could also be of a solution here, but, even if it is, I wonder what an experienced eye would say the book is expecting me to do.  (I have not yet used the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in this section of the book yet.)

**Reference**.  This exercise is number $38$ in section $2.3$ of Stewart's Calculus 6th edition translated to the Portuguese language.  The original 6th edition seems to ask us to prove $\sqrt{x} [1 + \sin^2(2\pi/x)] = 0$ as $x$ approaches zero from the right.  This problem from the original version seems to be [concerned with the Squeeze Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171291) and not the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: The point is that $\frac 1e \leq e^{\sin(\pi/x)} \leq e$ which you used in your attempt. That is enough to yield the answer via the squeeze theorem : basically, you're using the fact that $-1 \leq \sin y \leq 1$ for all $y$ and then putting $y = \frac{\pi}{x}$. This will also help answer the question from Stewart's Calculus in the end. The limit from the left? Depends on how you define $\sqrt{x}$ there, of course : if $\sqrt{x}$ isn't defined to the left of $0$ then you can't approach $0$ from the left while staying in the domain of $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: You could also use $y := \frac{1}{x}$ and have a look at $y\rightarrow \infty$. You get $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{y}}\leq x e^{\sin{\pi\cdot x}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ and again by squeeze theorem, you get $0$ as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\sin$ function is bounded below by -1 and above by 1. Thus $e^{\sin\frac{\pi}{x}}$ is bounded below by $e^{-1}$ and above by $e$.Since $\sqrt x$ approaches $0$ from the right, so does your function.